# UI elements for selecting date and time (not just date) in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the past I have used a combination of dateInput and a slider to get date and hour for my shiny app. I was wondering if there is a better option available now as I need to collect input up to the minute.

Searching online did not help so asking SO.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Its been quite sometime since this question has been posed but I'm guessing it remains relevant since I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer to retrieve time inputs.

Below are 3 examples to retrieve a time input.

1. The first is what I believe most people, myself included, had been or are looking for. A shiny like input time object for time input retrieval. It uses the HTML time input:< input id='ui_time' type='time'> followed by some simple javascript function to retrieve the input data before passing to the Shiny.onInputChange() function to pass as an input to the Shiny server.

   `<input id="ui_time" type="time">`

   `'<script>
       document.getElementById("ui_time").onchange = function() {
           var time = document.getElementById("ui_time").value;
           Shiny.onInputChange("input_html", time);
       };
    </script>'`
2. The second, which is probably not desired but sticks to the use of sliders, is a simple but cumbersome hack to create 2 sliders, one to register the time and another to register the minutes before concatenating the 2 results to return a proper time input.

   `sliderInput("slider_hours", "Hours:", min=0, max=23, value=0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("slider_mins", "Mins:",min = 0, max = 59, value = 0, step = 1)`
3. Lastly, if date and time formats are required, some may not be aware, as I had not, that the slider does accept date time inputs as POSIXt objects. In this case, a slider input can be constructed as follows:

   `sliderInput("slider_datetime", "Date & Time:", 
               min=as.POSIXlt("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "GMT"),
               max=as.POSIXlt("2020-01-01 23:59:59", "GMT"),
               value=as.POSIXlt("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "GMT"),
               timezone = "GMT")`

For those less familiar with shiny or html, you can view a functional sample code at my github: https://github.com/krenova/Shiny_TimeInput/blob/master/app.R

or simply run the following gist in R:

`runGist('https://gist.github.com/krenova/fc184de17892905182a422c96117e989')`

I'm new to shiny and html, picked it up just last week, so please bear in mind that I may not have done things in the most appropriate manner. In any case, I hope the above saves someone hours of time!

Comment: You just beat me to an answer, but you might be interested in the `shinyTime` package I just wrote ;) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38440748/1439843

Comment: Solution 1 is the one I was hoping for as well, but it doesn't work in Firefox, and RStudio uses Firefox to show shiny apps :(

Comment: haha what a strange coincidence. Thanks, wish your package was released earlier, took hours for me to find a solution! Wasnt aware that it wouldnt work on firefox too. +1 :)

Answer (score 8):

You can now use the package [`shinyTime`](https://github.com/burgerga/shinyTime) to intuitively input time into a Shiny App. At the moment it works with separate numeric inputs, that together make up time in the `%H:%M` or `%H:%M:%S` format. Getting and setting the value in R is done with a [`DateTime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/DateTimeClasses) object.

Example usage (also see the [example on shinyapps](https://burgerga.shinyapps.io/shinyTimeExample/)):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("shinyTime Example App"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        timeInput("time_input", "Enter time", value = strptime("12:34:56", "%T"))
      ),

      mainPanel(
        textOutput("time_output")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$time_output <- renderText(strftime(input$time_input, "%T"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Disclaimer:** I am the package author. Feedback and suggestions most welcome!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only lets you select hour:minute:second (time info), but not date-time info as the original question asked, is that correct?

Comment: @DeanAttili, yes you are correct, however, the original question asked for better options, and I think this is at the moment the best option.

Comment: It's been a while since your `shinyTime` package was released @Gerhard. I can't see an option to step the minutes by 15 minutes or 30 minutes as stepping at a 1 minute interval would usually not be always useful. Do we have a work around to step through the minute field at a higher than 1 interval?

Comment: Also the `data.table` package coerces the input time object from POSIX LT to POSIX CT with a warning: `POSIXlt column type detected and converted to POSIXct. We do not recommend use of POSIXlt at all because it uses 40 bytes to store one date.`

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra Thanks for your comments, I added them to my to-do list for the next release! (https://github.com/burgerga/shinyTime/issues)

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra I added the interval function to `shinyTime` v1.0.0, which should be available on CRAN in the following days! You can check out https://burgerga.shinyapps.io/shinyTimeExample/.

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra I think `POSIXlt` is a convenient default, but if you want `POSIXct` simply use `as.POSIXct` on the input object, eg, `as.POSIXct(input$time_input)`

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem, and I ended up making it a text field. I pre-populated the text field to show the users the proper format, and added checking (using `try` to make sure the field was properly formatted before doing anything.

From UI.R

```
textInput("fromDatetime", "From:", value = "9999-99-99 99:99:99" )
```

And then in server.R

```
  fromDTtry = try(as.POSIXct(fromDatetime))

  if (!(is.POSIXct(fromDTtry))) {
    return ("From date/time not formatted correctly")
  } else {
... }
```

I hope this helps. Hopefully Shiny will get around to native date/time support soon.