# Shiny: make date and time appear as expected in selection input

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a dataframe with the first column formatted as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and classified as POSIXct. `dput()` of small part of dataframe:

```
structure(list(`TIMESTAMP-TS` = structure(c(1432054800, 1432058400, 1432062000, 1432065600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
`RECORD-RN` = 4099:4102, `BattV_Min-Volts` = c(12.34, 12.36, 
12.35, 12.35), `ETos-DegC` = c(0.097, 0.047, 0.042, 0.023
), `Rso-DegC` = c(3.436, 3.52, 3.385, 3.053)), .Names = c("TIMESTAMP-TS", "RECORD-RN", "BattV_Min-Volts", "ETos-DegC", "Rso-DegC"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to use a range from this column to select the data in the other columns. The `dateRangeInput` won't work with the hours, I thought I'd try `inputSelect`. This works especially because I have multiple data sets that have different timesteps, i.e. 5 minute intervals, 1 minute intervals.

These are the lines of code I have written in the Shiny ui.R file for selecting date and time:

```
selectInput('starttime','Beginning date and time:', choices = data$'TIMESTAMP-TS', selectize = FALSE, size = 4),

selectInput('finishtime','Ending date and time:', choices = data$'TIMESTAMP-TS', selectize = FALSE, size = 4)
```

When Shiny runs, the drop-down shows the dates and times as total seconds since 1970. I thought wrapping `data$'TIMESTAMP-TS'` with `as.POSIXct()` would change it to the human readable form, but it didn't.

I tried letting the data read in as default class instead and then adding `as.POSIXct()` in the ui.R file for Shiny, but it still showed as cumulative seconds. The one interesting side effect of that experiment was getting a sort of rug on the plot that added more labels for the hours, which is useful, since the first plots I made had no indication of time, just the date.

What should I be using to make the drop-down options more understandable? I saw this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198515/ui-elements-for-selecting-date-and-time-not-just-date-in-shiny), but it seems like it'd be easier to use the `selectInput` since that uses the timesteps in the increments as they appear in the data sets.

Comment: I recall using as.character() successfully in similar situations, albeit within an xtable. It had something to do with how shiny renders the stuff. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested a toy model with this:

```
 selectInput(inputId = "choosevar",
                label = "Choose Cut Variable:",
                choices = as.character(df$`TIMESTAMP-TS`))
```

Note that R doesn't like minus signs in variable names normally, so you need to use the little tick sign under the tilde, whatever it's called (back quote?).

[image: pics or it didn't happen]