# Shiny timeInput is too tight

Tags: r, shiny

I have used timeInput in a big project (not convenient to troubleshoot) as below:

```
timeInput("test1", "Test Label", value = strptime("18:00", "%H:%M"))
```

The fluidPage shows it as:

[image]

I wonder if anyone knows what's the problem or simple workaround.

I have run the shinyTimeExample and make my own simple example. Both work without a problem. I have the latest ShinyTime package version 1.0.3.

EDIT: I inspected both the project element and the other working element as suggested by GriffoGoes (thanks). There seems to be no difference or any CSS applied. Elements below:

**Project:**

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="23" step="1" value="18" style="width: 8ch" class="form-control shinytime-hours">
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="59" value="00" style="width: 8ch" class="form-control shinytime-mins">
                  </div>
```

**Working example:**

```
<div class="input-group">
                      <input type="number" min="0" max="23" step="1" value="22" style="width: 8ch" class="form-control shinytime-hours">
                      <input type="number" min="0" max="59" value="39" style="width: 8ch" class="form-control shinytime-mins">
                    </div>
```

Also the problem is the same on a browser (Chrome) and on RStudio.

Comment: As you mentioned that the demo/example works (I guess in same browser), your issue is likely related to some CSS being applied (big projects = more chances for CSS applying where it is unexpected). Inspect the rendered element and check its `padding`. I was able to reproduce your issue setting a `padding-right: 15px` while the original value should be `12px`.  The fix is either adjusting the original CSS or creating a new CSS to adjust for these inputs.

Comment: Thank you GriffoGoes. That's a great suggestion. Yet, I couldn't solve the problem. See my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the issue is a result of a "conflict" between `shinyThemes` and `shinyTime` packages, it is hard to call this as a bug in either packages (but I guess you could check the packages/maintainers and see).

The quick solution is to use/adjust the current CSS to required values. Quick and dirty example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
  # Custom CSS to override sandstone settings
  tags$head(
    # Note the wrapping of the string in HTML()
    tags$style(HTML("
      .shinytime-hours , .shinytime-mins , .shinytime-secs {
        padding-right: 12px;
      }"))
  ),
  titlePanel("shinyTime Example App"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      timeInput("time_input", "Enter time", value = strptime("12:34:56", "%T"))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("time_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$time_output <- renderText(strftime(input$time_input, "%T"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In bigger applications there is likely an external CSS file already, where these changes would be more appropriated. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Alternatively, a new feature could be developed in the shinyTime package to allow custom CSS class/style settings - use https://github.com/burgerga/shinyTime/issues for that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out inspired by GriffoGoes comment. In the project I set theme = shinytheme("sandstone"). That seems to screw up timeInput.

Reproducible example below ([modified this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198515/ui-elements-for-selecting-date-and-time-not-just-date-in-shiny)):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
  titlePanel("shinyTime Example App"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      timeInput("time_input", "Enter time", value = strptime("12:34:56", "%T"))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("time_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$time_output <- renderText(strftime(input$time_input, "%T"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good catch! added an answer with the quick fix. The "better" fix would involve changing either libraries - probably the shinyTime - to allow more flexibility/better compatibility.